# qsub: is it possible to use both the "-k" and "-o" parameters?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

Recently I had to move from a computing cluster with LSF (bsub) to one that uses Torque (qsub).

On the prevous cluster I was able to check my jobs on the fly with the `bpeek` command.

On the new cluster this command is not available (neither `qpeek`). In the PBS documentation I see that the `-k` parameter allows to retain the output on the execution host  ([link](https://docs.loni.org/wiki/Checking_standard_output_of_PBS_jobs_in_real_time)). The problem here is the name of the log file cannot be defined by the user (using for example the `-o` parameter) so a new file is created everytime I submit a job.

Is there a way to define the name of the log file and still keep the `-k` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you're out of luck. Even the documentation for the current version states that this option overrides the path name for the given stream/s. However, it IS open source, so I'm sure they'd accept a pull request. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Torque can be set to not spool the output and write directly to the output file using $spool_as_final_name in the mom's config file. As a user, you might not have control of this, but some sites prefer this setup, so you can ask your admin. If they have it enabled, then you can simply `tail -f <output file>`